# SSLError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fafcebook.com', port=443)

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to get response from the server for server status with this code

```
import requests
import urllib3
try:
    r = requests.get('https://gookle.com')
    print r.status_code
    print r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as timeoutext:
    print timeoutext
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects as tooMany:
    print tooMany
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print ("OOps: Something Else", e)
except requests.ConnectionError as cr:
    print cr
```

The proble is here when I am puting right url like `https://www.google.com` it is ok but when I put `**https://www.gookle.com**` wrong url secont time output:
 `('OOps: Something Else', SSLError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fafcebook.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)'),))",),))`